# Unable to tag users to a fb photo uploaded via graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I just testing something and found out by script not working . It actually upload a pic and then use it pic id to tag some random peoples from the friend lists . My app have `user_photos,publish_stream` permissions . I can successfully upload the photo but i am getting error on making tags .

Here is The code:

```
    $f1 = $facebook->api('me/friends?limit=19');

$img = $_REQUEST['imgl'];
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$args = array(      
    'message' => $_REQUEST['m_Config']['appTitle'], 
    'source' => '@' . $img,
    'access_token' => $access_token, 
);
$photo = $facebook->api ( $user . '/photos', 'post', $args );   
foreach($f1['data'] as $fbu){
    $tagx = array('tag_uid' => $fbu['id'],'x' => rand(100,350),'y' => rand(100,350));
    $ftags[] = $tagx;
}

$args = array (
    'tags' => json_encode($ftags),
    'access_token' => $access_token,
);

$result = $facebook->api('/' . $photo['id'] . '/tags', 'post', $args);
print_r($result);
```

Now the Error which , I am getting is `Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Invalid parameter thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb\base_facebook.php on line 1254`

My question is where , My code is wrong . WHy I am getting error , I also tried searching but cant get it fixed .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be assigning the tags at random locations for random friends, which is completely wrong.
The user should be selecting where in the photo their friends are - anything else would be against policy and likely to be shut down as spam

As for your code problem, this isn't working because `tag_uid` isn't a listed parameter name in the API - the parameter to use for specifying which user to tag is `to`

See the [Photo object's Tag connection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags) documentation for more details and some example code.

Comment: it is a test project for me so usage is limited to personal just to learn and practice . About the code if i am sending multiple tags there should be used `tag_uid` but as you told i still tried and got this error `Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Invalid keys "to" were found in param "tags"` .

Comment: I just checked and it's definitely supposed to be 'to'

Comment: I checked by using "to" in the place of "tag_uid" it still gives error but the error is different from the first one . `Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Invalid keys "to" were found in param "tags". thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb\base_facebook.php on line 1254` .